# Getting total number of post in current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've trying to display the number of posts in current page while using pagination. For the total posts among all pages I've used `$query->found_posts;`. However, I have no clue about counting post on each page. For example, I want to display ***Showing 5 of 50 posts*** Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the $query->found_posts; return an array? if it does then you can try adding count($query->found_posts);

Comment: please share the code you wrote so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to `found_posts`, there's also `post_count`, which represents "the number of posts for the current query". So you can use `$query->post_count`.

Ref: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/0ea7a38664746f9ad4f402768975c66928817531/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L100